# ASP.NET, XSLT, extracting values from a CDATA section

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

i have a small problem i have xome xml with a cdata section. This CDATA section contains fragments of HTMl. I would like to extract some of the data inside this CDATA element. Right now i have a XSLT transformation that outputs the rest of the document as HTMl, but i need only a small part of the CDATA HTML, not the entire part - e.g. a my Title tag. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT won't read the CDATA section as anything other than text. You'll need to pre-parse your data before handing it over to XSLT. You could use a preparsing script (written in Python, PHP, Perl, VB, whatever) and then do one of (but not limited to) the following:

- remove the `CDATA` tags and allow XSLT to handle the undesired content
- move the `<title>` tag to a XSLT accesible place outside the `CDATA` tags
- maybe using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in Python (<strike>or a [cthulhu-inducing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) regex</strike>) get the desired value out of the `CDATA` section, and pass the desired value as a parameter to XSLT

Comment: @Jweede: Srsly. The regex did not deserve mentioning.